# How can I get the number of rows of a detail grid?

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to get the number of rows in documents Details grid. I don't know how to call this inside of another instance.

for example: In this method I receive row by row, I want to know how can I get the total number of rows received.

```cs
public virtual void ARTran_RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
{
    var row = (ARTran)e.Row;
}
```

[This is for screen Invoices and Meme (AR301000)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAP1L.png)

Comment: Use a property?

Answer (score 1):

Do a `.Select()` of your data view and use the `Count` property.

```cs
var rowCount = Base.Transactions.Select().Count;
```

In your case, you want the data view used by the detail grid, which is `Transactions`. You can find more info on how the screen in builded by using the Inspect Element tool. You can read more about it on http://acumaticaopenuniversity.com/pdf/T300_Acumatica_Cust_Platform.pdf